# cluster genetic programming/algorithms

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, genetic-algorithm

Recently I have been trying to understand if hadoop clusters can be used for genetic algorithms/programming jobs. I've been reading about hadoop and I understand that it can parallize processing of large datasets. in my case, I wouldn't have large data sets.. but what i would find really useful are the parallelizing capabilities of hadoop. So, my question is whether a program like hadoop can be used for evaluating or processing genetic algorithms/programming which I think will be more processing oriented as opposed I/O oriented?

Comment: Is it possible that no one is interested in answering this question?

Answer (score 1):

As you know maximum Bio-informatics algo is based on Combination,cutting,splicing,edit distance,Neural network,..etc and also backtracking like dfs (for partial digest).If you make them distribute like a map-reduce job for particular instance or length ex :

```
For length 1 ..... map-reduce job 1
For length 2 ..... map-reduce job 2
.
.
.
For length n ..... map-reduce job n
```

Or if you want to compare Bio-info algo with the architecture of hadoop you can find simple algo in this link >> http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2011/01/introduction-to-bioinformatics.html

Hope it helps.